# Using Regex expression with toHaveProperty() in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a scenario where my Promise rejects with an Error object.

```
throw new Error(`${ISSUE}`);
```

ISSUE contains a common string `is causing this issue`.
Some examples of this can be:

```
ISSUE = 'Node is causing this issue', OR
ISSUE = 'Jest is causing this issue'
```

To test this scenario using Jest, I am using `toHaveProperty()` just like:

```
expect(function()).rejects.toHaveProperty('message',/is causing this issue/);
```

But it is giving me error saying

```
Comparing two different types of values. Expected regexp but received string.
```

It works perfect when specifying the exact string here. Any way to work this round with regex?

I have tried this though which seems to be working but looking for a cleaner and simplified approach.

```
return function()
  .then()
  .catch((e) => {
    expect(e.message).toMatch(/is causing this issue/);
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`toMatchObject`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchobjectobject):

```
expect(function()).rejects.toMatchObject({
  message: expect.stringMatching(/is causing this issue/)
});
```

This will allow any object that has a `message` property whose value is a string matching the given RegExp.

Comment: Super great!! Just a small correction in the syntax worked great. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked! Where did you correct it? I’ll update the answer.

Comment: Very small changes like rejects is not a function and removing the semi-colon
The final one:

expect(function()).rejects.toMatchObject({
  message: expect.stringMatching(/is causing this issue/),
});

Comment: Whoops! My bad. Thank you.